# Deletions on arbitrary data structure

Tags: data-structures

Let A be some data structure. Claim:
If we delete first 3 and then 4 we will get the same structure as if we delete first 4 and then 3. The claim is true when A is:

1. A binary search tree.
2. A hash table where collisions are solved by linked lists.
3. 1+2.
4. None of the above.

The answer according to given solutions is 2. I don't understand why and I can't find a counter example to 1. I think the correct answer should be 3.

Could someone explain? Thanks!